# CSS positioning of "before" element

Tags: css, image, icons

I have a question about CSS positioning of `:before` element to a parent element.

Let's say I have a parent element `div` like a block of text with `background` and `padding` properties and I want to add a small image or icon to this `div` (e.g. in the right-top corner) and I want this small element to stay there even when resizing the window.

How can I achieve that? Here is a code for `:before` I tried:

```
.blure:before {
    content: URL(/image.svg);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 73%;
    margin-top: -14%;
}
```

Comment: No issues with the code I think. Always follow double colon for pseudo elements. Check your image url, size, class name and positioning values if not working..

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_before

Answer (score 0):

After setting the absolute you can give the left, right, top, bottom properties to element

```
.blure:before{
   content: URL(/image.svg);
   display: absolute;
   top: 15px;
   right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: @MiroFaltinek, please don't forget to [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it has been useful to solve your issues